# What means "作狀"?

Tags: cantonese

I think [this adjective (形容词 )](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BD%9C%E7%8A%B6) only exists in Cantonese?  Google didn't return  official dictionary website. [粤语里的“作状、单打”是什么意思？_百度知道](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1690741088764244428.html)

> 作状就是装b，丑人多作怪的意思；单单打打就是说话难听，尖酸刻薄，指桑骂槐，含沙射影

I stumbled this 形容词 in comment under [【廣東話】獲頒友誼小姐唔得閒慶祝 鄺美璇：覆咗成晚MSG - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbwjefcqMVU)

> 反而覺得好**作狀** [尤其](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%A4%E5%85%B6#Chinese)啲[尾音](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%BE%E9%9F%B3)

I think this means

> On the contrary, this feels very **作狀**. Especially  final sound; last or end syllable.

Comment: There is a Cantonese dictionary http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15708/ 作狀: dramatize

Answer (score 1):

Half right...

[CantoDic - 作狀](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15708/)

It means "**dramatize**" in English. It Mandarin Chinese meaning should be "**忸怩作态**" in my opinion.

The answer on Baidu Zhidao used dirty words and too colloquial.

So the translation of 反而覺得好作狀 is "But feel so fake".